# How can I export the stamp annotation from image to an image file?

Tags: c#, image, itext, pdf-annotations

How can I export the “stamp annotation from image” to an image file?

I have a pdf which contains stamp annotions (in fact it's an image), I want to export all these kinds of images to file and get the x/y position.

I am new to pdf. Any idea or code will be appreciated.

**[--- Edited on 2019/08/08 ---]**

> ```
>     private void btnExtractAnnotaion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(this.txtPdf.Text);
>         PdfDictionary pageDict = reader.GetPageN(reader.NumberOfPages);
>         PdfArray annotArray = pageDict.GetAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);
>         PdfObject annot = null;
>         Console.WriteLine("Annotation count:{0}", annotArray.Size);
>         for (int i = 0; i < annotArray.Size; i++)
>         {
>             annot = annotArray.GetDirectObject(i);
>             Console.WriteLine(annot.ToString());
>             //curAnnot = annotArray.GetAsDict(i);
>             //Console.WriteLine(curAnnot.ToString());
>             bool btmp = annot.IsDictionary();
>             if (btmp)
>             {
>                 PdfDictionary pdfDic = ((PdfDictionary)annot);
>                 PdfName stamp = pdfDic.GetAsName(PdfName.SUBTYPE);
>                 if (stamp.Equals(PdfName.STAMP))
>                 {
>                     //PdfObject img = pdfDic.GetDirectObject(PdfName.RECT);
>                     // How Can I get the image(png, jpg...) of Stamp?
>                 }
>             }
> ```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]

Comment: **A** Please share the example file on a service that does not require registration, and that also does not drown you in adds. Public shares on Google drive or Dropbox are good options. **B** Have you looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51113117/1729265)? It shows how to copy an image from a source annotation to some target annotation. you actually only need to use the part extracting the image from the source...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@mkl @FastJack Thanks for your time!
By this answer [ImageRenderListener](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51113117/1729265)

It solved my problem. The following are my codes:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(this.txtPdf.Text);
PdfDictionary pageDict = reader.GetPageN(reader.NumberOfPages);
PdfArray annotArray = pageDict.GetAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);

//Console.WriteLine("Annotation count:{0}", annotArray.Size);
for (int i = 0; i < annotArray.Size; i++)
{
    PdfObject annot = annotArray.GetDirectObject(i);
    //Console.WriteLine(annot.ToString());
    bool btmp = annot.IsDictionary();
    if (btmp)
    {
        PdfDictionary pdfDic = ((PdfDictionary)annot);
        PdfName stamp = pdfDic.GetAsName(PdfName.SUBTYPE);
        if (stamp.Equals(PdfName.STAMP))
        {
            // rects are laid out [llx, lly, urx, ury]
            float x, y, width, height;
            PdfArray rect = pdfDic.GetAsArray(PdfName.RECT);
            x = rect.GetAsNumber(0).FloatValue;
            y = rect.GetAsNumber(1).FloatValue;
            width = rect.GetAsNumber(2).FloatValue - x;
            height = rect.GetAsNumber(3).FloatValue - y;

            PdfDictionary appearancesDic = pdfDic.GetAsDict(PdfName.AP);
            PdfStream normalAppearance = appearancesDic.GetAsStream(PdfName.N);
            PdfDictionary resourcesDic = ormalAppearance.GetAsDict(PdfName.RESOURCES);

            ImageRenderListener listener = new ImageRenderListener();
            PdfContentStreamProcessor processor = new PdfContentStreamProcessor(listener);
            processor.ProcessContent(
                ContentByteUtils.GetContentBytesFromContentObject(normalAppearance),                 resourcesDic);

            System.Drawing.Image drawingImage = listener.Images.First();
            //Image image = Image.GetInstance(drawingImage, drawingImage.RawFormat);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

iText7 is exactly the thing you want to use for that. ;)

https://www.nuget.org/packages/itext7/

https://itextpdf.com/en/products/itext-7

This is how you could get access to the stamps, depending on the stamping technique used:

```
using (PdfReader r = new PdfReader("input.pdf"))
using (PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument(r))
{
    var annotations = doc.GetPage(1).GetAnnotations();
}
```

on other occasions this could do the trick:

```
using (PdfReader r = new PdfReader("input.pdf"))
using (PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument(r))
{
    var res = doc.GetFirstPage().GetResources();
}
```

unless you provide a demo-pdf, that all the help i can give you

Comment: Thanks, But I prefer to itext5.

Comment: file expired -.- can you re-send? sorry, wasn't online this weekend

Comment: and iText5 is not that different in usage. also if you have that preference, you could post your test here, should result in less work for the helpers here then

Comment: I'm so Sorry! new link here https://pan.baidu.com/s/12JYYfCacHHv4pMYx-DLIeg

Comment: Any sample code which expor the annotation image from pdf will be appreciated.

Comment: can you please upload anywhere more international and most important without the need to register?!

Comment: and again: can you please post some of your trial-code? so helpers can build on top of that?